# Port 25 open / Postfix installed, but no mail being sent out

Tags: apache, smtp, postfix-mta

I've installed Postfix, opened port 25 (as well as ports 110, 995, 143, and 993) on my local computer connected to the Internet, but none of the e-mails that I am attempting to send out using the localhost:25 definition are being properly routed to their destination. Basically, I am trying to set up a local SMTP server to send out e-mails from my production website's software (also hosted on the same local computer).

I am using Verizon FIOS Internet service, who reportedly blocks port 25 (but actually does **not** in my case, as I have enabled it and checked that is in fact accessible from my external IP address). I have attempted to send the e-mail using no Smart Host, then using Verizon's SMTP server as a Smart Host, and finally using Verizon/Yahoo's SMTP server as a Smart Host, but none of them have worked.

What could be causing this issue?

I really appreciate any help on this problem, because I've been working to no success on it for the past three hours. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: are you able to  `telnet alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 25` from that box? it looks like google is ignoring you for some reason. - could be blacklisted, port could actually be blocked still.

Comment: You're right, I'm not able to telnet it! I don't think I should be blacklisted, this is just a residential IP address I'm on. When you say the port could be blocked, do you mean that my inability to telnet Google could be because Verizon has in fact blocked all access on port 25? (Thanks again for all help!)

Comment: When I telnet localhost 25, however, it responds with: 220 ESMTP Postfix. Also when I telnet my IP address 25, it responds with a successful access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

absolutely, it's very common for large ISPs to block outbound connections on port 25 ~ they do this specifically to prevent what you are attempting. You should give them a call and verify if this is the case.

OR

See if you can configure your postfix to authenticate on your verizon mail account and relay your mail through that. [actually I did exactly this ~ I'll see if I can dig up the config]

-sean

**UPDATE**

here we go:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Sorry, I'm a little crunched on time, you'll have to dig up the docs for postfix relaying and how to setup the password maps [cause I don't recall offhand]

Hope his helps...

Comment: Please do tell me if you find the config information. I tried several times to set up a Smart Host via Verizon, but it never seemed to work out.. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup MX record in DNS (reverse DNS must work properly) and the respective domain name (FDQN) in the smpt demon ?

Comment: We were previously on Google Apps before I've been attempting to set up our own local mail server, so I haven't touched the MX records (pointed all to Google right now). How should I go about setting up the MX records for my local set up - pointing it to my IP address?

Comment: that's how I did it - MX record for my domain poiting to the ip of the server sending out the email